# If energy is drained from a capacitor linearly, does capacitor voltage decrease linearly as well?

Tags: power, capacitor, current, basic

[image: Circuit]

If a charged capacitor is connected to a current source and resistor as shown above, the resistor is constantly consuming 0.001J/s. If you were to make an energy-time graph of the capacitor, you would see a straight linear decrease.

These equations hold for a capacitor:

\$ I = C \frac{dV}{dt} \$ (1)

\$ V = I\frac{t}{C} + D \$ (2) <= this is a linear decrease of voltage
Thus, because I is also constant, you would see a straight linear decrease in a voltage-time graph as the capacitor is discharging.

However, the energy of a capacitor is

\$E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2\$ (3)

and the voltage is

\$ V = \sqrt{2 \frac{E}{C}} \$ (4)

If the energy inside the cap is decreasing linearly, how can the voltage be also decreasing linearly according to that equation?

Comment: Please note that the capital S is the symbol for siemens, not seconds....use the lower case s. Also a J/s is a watt, which is power, not energy. Please check your math on the resistor...I don't think it is dissipating anything close to a watt.

Comment: I already corrected it for you while formatting the equations, but in the future please mind your capitalizations. Your V, C, and I was a mix of upper and lowercase too.  Because of the mix, it was difficult to tell whether you actually intended to have lower case Vs and Is at some places as an instantaneous non-constant value

Comment: This is a bad circuit. You need initial conditions also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the energy inside the cap is decreasing linearly, how can the voltage be also decreasing linearly according to that equation?

In your circuit, the current source is absorbing or supplying energy, so the resistor is not the only place the capacitor energy can be transferred to.
When the capacitor is charged above 0.1 V, the current source will be absorbing energy, and when the capacitor charge is below 0.1 V, the current source will be supplying energy.

If you consider the energy absorbed by both the current source and the resistor, they will add up to the energy being discharged from the capacitor.

> If you were to make an energy-time graph of the capacitor, you would see a straight linear decrease.

This is not correct.

Comment: If I were to replace the 1k resistor with a 10kOhm resistor, the resistor would be consuming energy 10 times as fast. Yet, with eqn (2), the cap voltage decrease rate would be the same. Is this because the current source is supplying energy in this case?

Comment: Remember, its a current source and can expend infinite voltage to keep the current going... so your last statement needs some work

Comment: @person314314314 You keep ignoring the question of the capacitor voltage vs. the resistor voltage. The two will only be the same for an instant of time, then the current source will be providing or absorbing power. You can not neglect this in your calculations.

Comment: @person314314314, yes, if you have 10 kOhms, and the capacitor intially charged above 1 V, then the source will be supplying power for all t > 0.

Answer (score 1):

You will see a linear decrease in the capacitor voltage, but that is because you are drawing constant current, not constant power.  The power you're drawing from the capacitor decreases with decreasing voltage.

Energy is the integral of power over time, so it makes little sense to refer to "constant energy" unless no power is being drawn at all.

Answer (score 0):

> If the energy inside the cap is decreasing linearly, how can the
>   voltage be also decreasing linearly according to that equation?

The initial conditions aren't specified which are important for any capacitor calculations. But the current source will try to force 100mA through the capacitor, the only way to do this is to continually increase (or decrease depending on which direction your looking from) the voltage.

Now if we started the capacitor with a charge on it, we would see the voltage change, but the current source would keep on charging the capacitor forever (because it has infinite energy to expend, and our capacitor is ideal). It doesn't make sense to worry about the energy when the source can expend energy infinitely

[image]